# Data for binary systems

Tags: resource-recommendations, astronomy, data-analysis, binary-stars

I am looking for binary systems data that can be used in the context of Kepler's laws. Masses, distances, periods, etc.

Comment: see if this binary star database helps: http://bdb.inasan.ru/

Comment: Would [astronomy.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic Is anything to do with the sky off-topic here? I can understand that observational astronomy is perhaps best asked there, but this is squarely an astrophysics question.

Comment: @Qmechanic I added this question to Astronomy and got 3 down-votes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to read this paper

> Accurate masses and radii of normal stars: modern results and applications. G. Torres, J. Andersen and A. Gimenez. [*Astron. Astrophys. Rev.* **18** no. 1-2, pp. 67-126 (2010)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00159-009-0025-1), [arXiv:0908.2624](http://arxiv.org/abs/0908.2624).

You can find links to systems with orbits and accurate fundamental parameters there. Some of them calculated on the base of third Kepler's law.

See also:

> [Fourth Catalog of Interferometric Measurements of Binary Stars](http://www.usno.navy.mil/USNO/astrometry/optical-IR-prod/wds/int4/fourth-catalog-of-interferometric-measurements-of-binary-stars), US Naval Observatory, 2012,

and

> [The Washington Double Star Catalog](http://www.usno.navy.mil/USNO/astrometry/optical-IR-prod/wds/WDS), US Naval Observatory, 2012.

where you can request data for orbit plotting.

Maybe my question [How to plot orbit of binary star and calculate its orbital elements?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1348/how-to-plot-orbit-of-binary-star-and-calculate-its-orbital-elements) at Astronomy.SE will help you too.

Comment: Hi Astronomer, and welcome to the site! I took the liberty of editing the formatting of your references; I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try the [VizieR online catalog of astronomical databases](http://vizier.u-strasbg.fr/viz-bin/VizieR)

Put "binary stars" in the search box and you will find many databases, many of which will include the sort of orbital parameters you are looking for.